# Apps scripts FixedFooter covers input selection

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having an issue with the `FixedFooter` class in my gmail addon. Basically if there is enough items in the `SelectionInput` the last few items get covered by the FixedFooter.

For example in the image bellow there is supposed to be 50 items but the last five are hidden behind the FixedFooter (the create project button). Is there any solution to this?

[image: An image of fixedfooter covering input options]

Comment: Have you considered making a nested dropdown? For example in the first dropdown you have the users choose between `1-10`, `11-20` etc. and in the second then between the 10 inputs corresponding to their first choice.

Comment: That would be a choice but i think it would slow down the process too much since it could be hard for the user to find the exact item this way. I started thinking about adding empty items at the end to push the last items upward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/172037701), already filed on Google's Issue Tracker and being worked on.

While waiting for it to be fixed, your workaround of adding empty items at the bottom is a good way to get aorund it.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the user is on mobile device? Because this problem doesn't appear in the gmail mobile app.